# How can i get this script working?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, input

The Script(input.sh):

```
echo "What is your name?"

if [[ $1 =~ "*" ]]
then
read name1
read name2
echo "Are you really "$name1 "??? or" $name2 "?"
else
echo "Are you really "$1 "??? or" $2 "?"
fi
```

What I want is if I run the command:`./input.sh fahad Eclipse`

Then it should print:

```
What is your name?
Are you really fahad ??? or Eclipse ?
```

Also, if I do this: `./input.sh`

Then it should ask me for input and then print the line.

How can I do that ?

Comment: `$1 =~ "*"` uses regular expressions, but `*` at the start of an expression is just a `*`. Did you really mean that, or did you mean `[[ $1 == * ]]`, or simply, `[[ -n $1 ]]`?

Comment: By the way, please, please don't use multiple question marks. One is enough. Adding more doesn't make any sense syntactically and makes you look like a slightly demented 5-year-old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script isn't executing properly due to your if statement, the following should work.  It requires 2 args, or it will ask them name1 and name2.

The if statement contains '$#' which calculates the number of arguments given.  The follow '-ne' is the comparison operator for 'not equal to'.  Finally the last number is for how many you're expecting.  So in our case, we're looking for exactly 2, if 1, or 4 are given, the else statement will be executed.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What is your name?"

if [[ $# -ne 2 ]] ; then
read name1
read name2
echo "Are you really "$name1 "??? or" $name2 "?"
else
echo "Are you really "$1 "??? or" $2 "?"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)
Can you please explain "if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]" ?

Comment: I updated my answer to include the explanation.  Not realizing, it would unmark the answer being correct.  Please mark it correct if you're satisfied with the explanation.  :)